# multidimensional default array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've got two multidimensional arrays:

```
const defaultData = [
  ["ad", 0],
  ["ae", 0],
  ["af", 0]
]

const data = [
  ["az", 20],
  ["ad", 50]
]
```

The desired result is:

```
const expected = [
  ["ad", 50],
  ["ae", 0],
  ["af", 0]
]
```

Here az is ignored because its not valid because its not in the defaultData.
ad is valid and therefore the 0 is overwritten with the value of 50.

How would I best produce this result. Thanks?

Please assume neither array is sorted. The expected result need not be sorted either.

Either vanilla JS or Lodash is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the `defaultData`, and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to match each iterated array against `data`:

```js
const defaultData = [['ad', 0],['ae', 0],['af', 0]];
const data = [['az', 20],['ad', 50]];

const expected = defaultData.map(arr => {

  // Destructure the first element from `arr`
  // and assign it to `code`
  const [ code ] = arr;

  // `find` the array in `data` where the first element
  // matches `code`
  const found = data.find(el => el[0] === code);

  // If `found` is undefined return the whole array
  // otherwise return a new array with the code and the value
  // from the found array
  return found ? [code, found[1]] : arr;
});

console.log(expected);
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the `data` to an object (`dataByKey`) with `_.fromPairs()`. Map the `defaultData`, and check if the "key" (index 0) exists in `dataByKey`. If it is, create a new array with the value from `dataByKey`. If not return the original array.

```js
const defaultData = [
  ["ad", 0],
  ["ae", 0],
  ["af", 0]
]

const data = [
  ["az", 20],
  ["ad", 50]
]

const dataByKey = _.fromPairs(data)

const result = defaultData.map(o => o[0] in dataByKey ? [o[0], dataByKey[o[0]]] : o)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, I am using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to create a new Array and [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find elements from the second array.

I compare the first index item of each sub array from the default array, if any of the items from second array has the same element in its first index then I return it, if none matches, nothing is returned.

If I have a matched item then I create a new array using its elements.
If I don't have a matched item I create a new using the default elements of the default item.

```js
const defaultData = [
  ["ad", 0],
  ["ae", 0],
  ["af", 0]
]

const data = [
  ["az", 20],
  ["ad", 50]
]

let newData = defaultData.map(eachDefault => {
  let found = data.find(eachData => {
    if (eachData[0] == eachDefault[0]) {
      return true
    }
  })
  if (found) {
    return [...found]
  }
  return [...eachDefault]
})

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Answers saying _"Try this out:"_ are not appreciated. You should explain your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could first create one object from data and then use `map` method on defaultData to create new array and get value from data by key.

```js
const defaultData = [
  ["ad", 0],
  ["ae", 0],
  ["af", 0]
]

const data = [
  ["az", 20],
  ["ad", 50]
].reduce((r, [key, value]) => {
  r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + value;
  return r;
}, {})

const expected = defaultData.map(([key, value]) => {
  return [key, key in data ? data[key] : value] 
})

console.log(expected)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map/reduce like this:

```js
const defaultData = [
  ["ad", 0],
  ["ae", 0],
  ["af", 0]
]

const data = [
  ["az", 20],
  ["ad", 50]
]

const result = defaultData.map(arr => data.reduce(([dKey, dVal], [key, val]) => [ dKey, dKey === key ? val : dVal ], arr));

console.log(result);
```